# What will be the data type while using $_POST['name']

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to know what will be the data type while using $_POST['name'] suppose if I'm binding parameters:

```
$unsafe_variable1=$_POST['name'];
$unsafe_variable2=$_POST['email'];
$unsafe_variable3=$_POST['city'];

$stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (name, email, city) VALUES ('$bname', '$email', '$city')");

$obj->bind_param('sss', $unsafe_variable1, $unsafe_variable3, $unsafe_variable3);
```

My Guess is 's' for string.

---

And second thing is when I use sss I get a warning:

```
Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

That makes me think maybe 's' would not be the right datatype. :o

Comment: You don't have any `?` placeholders in your statement.  `$stmt=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (name, email, city) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");` You have just inserted the variables directly.

Comment: ...But the data types `sss` are correct, and the `bind_param()` call looks fine.

Comment: Ohh! I was reading the manual and I thought I need value names instead of '?'. :o :P Dumb me. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: It worked out! Thanks for the help. And thanks for letting me know that 's' is the correct data type. :)

Comment: I have another problem here. After executing the above prepared statement I want to use if condition and the condition is: $stmt->execute(); if (!mysqli_query($con,$stmt))  { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli)); }

Comment: But it says object given instead of parameter. I've always called liked this but now it's not working. :o

Comment: Check the manual more closely.  There will be no call to `mysqli_query()`.  The call to `$stmt->execute()` _is_ the entire action, so the pattern is `if ($stmt->execute()) { while ($stmt->fetch()) .... } else echo $mysqli->error;`

Comment: Prepared statements don't work much like regular query calls in MySQLi.

Comment: Actually, since this is an INSERT statement, you don't want to fetch of course.

Comment: hehe, yes I altered that already with { die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); } echo 'hello'; and everything is fine now. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice that you are using the variables directly:

```
[...] VALUES ('$bname', '$email', '$city')
```

Just change it to:

```
[...] VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

POST variables are usually strings. Therefore your `sss` binding is perfect. To avoid the problem in the future you can just:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable (name, email, city) VALUES (:name, :email, :city)");
$params['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$params['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$params['city'] = $_POST['city'];
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Which will automatically detect the type of the variable and bind it.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST & $_GET parameters will always be strings.

You can use gettype() to check,

`echo gettype($_POST['variable_from_form']);`

just for one example, and you will see that it will recognize `1` as string, `1.11` as string, `any text` as string and `true/false` as string instead of booleans. That is because php converts non-string values to strings using PHP's type juggling system.